# Как изменить родительский div через style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Имеется иерархия блоков div

```html
<div id="1">
     <div id="2">
          <div style="" id="3"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Можно ли через данный style (у `div` с `id=3`) изменить CSS свойства у `div` с `id=1`?
Например, если я хочу установить `<div id="1" style="padding: 5rem;">`

Comment: Ответ: через CSS нельзя. Через js можно, но при условии

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с js. метод -  [Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
Но имейте ввиду, при такой иерархии как у вас, стили могу применяться и к внутренним блокам.

```js
let block = document.querySelector('#id3');
block.closest('#id1').style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<div id="id1"> id1
  <div id="id2"> id2
    <div style="" id="id3">id3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если против моего добавления, - сделай откат. Возражать не буду

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Всё супер, спасибо. Я на SO пишу обычно чисто выделяя минутку, чтоб отвлечься от работы, и в браузере чаще всего просто уже нет места для новых вкладок чтоб загуглить нужные ссылки для написания расширенного ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, нельзя. Все ждут появления свойства [:has()](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas) но пока только Safary работает в этом направлении. Только через JS